# How can I answer if the question isn't accepting answers?

Tags: support, answers, new-users, protected-questions

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571213/how-can-i-force-a-hard-reload-in-chrome-for-android), and I know of a good solution for the problem. How can I share my solution?

The "Add a comment" button requires "50 reputation", but I have no idea about the "reputation". How can I "buy" 50 reputation?

I tried the "Edit" button, but I didn't want to reshape the original answer.

(The actual solution: because Google binds the Android devices with your desktop machine, refreshing the page on the desktop with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F5</kbd> will refresh even on the Android device.)

Comment: Ah, thanks, @rene. I didn't notice that because I didn't actually search for the question by its title. I think in that case this is probably not a duplicate. It is certainly *related*, but I think it would be more reasonable to answer Gabor's question directly. Especially if there isn't a [support] question about the interaction between a new user and a "protected" question.

Comment: I've unprotected the question now.

Comment: If it isn't clear from @MartinSmith's comment: That they changed the status of the question to unprotected means you should be able to answer the question now.

Answer (score 35):

What happened to you here is a bit of an edge case, so allow me to extend my apologies for the poor first impression.

You see, ***normally*, the way you share a solution to a question is by posting an answer.** At the bottom of every question page, you'll see a big textbox where you compose your answer (using [Markdown syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)), and then click the big blue "Post Your Answer" button:

[image: "Your Answer" textbox and "Post Your Answer" button]

This doesn't require any reputation and can be done by new users and veterans alike. Questions and answers are the lifeblood of this site, so we encourage *everyone* to share their solutions to questions (as long as they are different from the answers that have already been posted).

**Comments are a bit different.** We do restrict those for brand-new users by requiring that you have a minimum of 50 reputation in order to post them. This is designed to keep down spam and *shouldn't* be a big limitation to getting started—comments are intended for asking clarification questions and should be used sparingly. Complete questions ready to be answered don't require comments. And when you *do* get to 50 reputation, please don't post answers in comments.

[image: Comment box]

A brief note regarding [**reputation**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation): it isn't something that you purchase (everything here is free), it's something that you *earn*. How do you earn it? By contributing useful answers, of course! And also by posting good questions. This should have all been explained to you in the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). A few good answers is usually all you need to get to 50 reputation (a single upvote on an answer gets you 10 reputation—it adds up quickly!).

Anyway, all of this is how things *usually* work. **What happened in your case was that [the question you were looking at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571213/how-can-i-force-a-hard-reload-in-chrome-for-android) had been automatically ["protected"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-question) by the system, which restricted your ability to answer it.** Questions are [automatically protected](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89532/automatically-protect-questions-with-three-or-more-low-rep-user-deleted-answers) when they have been attracting a large number of spam, "thanks", and "me too" posts. As the Tour explains, these are *not* answers by Stack Overflow standards, and we don't want them in the answer box. To decrease moderation overhead, questions that have, for whatever reason, become targets for these types of non-answers get protected so that you need to have a token amount of reputation (10 points) to answer them.

I used the word "token" there because the system really does consider 10 reputation to be a very small amount. Only one upvote on an answer and you'll have enough to answer protected questions. Only brand-new users are barred from answering them. Unfortunately, there *are* edge cases where brand-new users have something constructive to share and our system gets in the way of that. That's what happened to you. Sorry.

On protected questions, the answer box isn't even shown to new users. Instead, there is a little yellow banner message that tries to spell this out:

[image: "protected by Community"]

The best thing for you to do would be to browse around and see if there is another question you can help to answer. If so, post that answer, get your upvote(s), and then come back and answer [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571213/how-can-i-force-a-hard-reload-in-chrome-for-android). Again, my apologies for the friction. Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thanks for trying to share your knowledge!

Comment: The answer box isn't even rendered when you're under 10 rep: https://i.stack.imgur.com/olrvi.png but I forgive you: it has been a while since you've  been at that rep level ... ;)

Comment: Indeed, it has been quite a while. I don't even think protected questions were a thing when I had 1 rep. I guess if I win this moderator thingadongdong I might need to finally break down and create a sockpuppet account. But, wow. Not showing the answer box is bad design. [Now where have I heard that before…?](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2008/07/01/dont-hide-or-disable-menu-items/)

Comment: "Don't remove them, grey them out"