# Penalizing new users by deleting good-faith answers to duplicate questions seems wrong

Tags: discussion

I joined Stack Overflow recently.  A few days ago I posted my first answer.  The questioner accepted my answer. A day or two later, the question was deleted as a duplicate, along with my answer and the points it earned.

The question was of a very basic nature and it was asked by someone obviously new to programming. I can see in retrospect that there was a high probability it was a question already asked and answered.

Nevertheless, I answered in good faith, using code examples written by me. Penalizing learners for their newbie mistakes seems harsh for a site that purports to support all comers in their efforts to learn and help.

I few minutes ago I tried to answer another question and found that my answering privileges have also been rescinded. I'm starting to see why there are so many online who see Stack Overflow as a place hostile to beginners.

Comment: It's highly unlikely that you lost your answer privilege because of one answer to a duplicate. Which error message do you get? Do you have any other deleted answers?

Comment: Or any other accounts which have been sanctioned or deleted? SE will merge multiple accounts into one, including any past histories or sanctions for all of them, when users create new accounts to get around bad histories or sanctions imposed on existing accounts. But regardless, the best advice is: SE is not a place for newbies to *learn* the craft, it’s for experienced people to *hone* it. Avoid answering newbie Qs, because it will always end up this way.

Comment: Content is curated, not users. If the question was not good or useful enough to keep around, better to delete it. No matter who had posted answers under it.

Comment: Do you have a link to the deleted question? Duplicates are normally not deleted, but will stay around quite some time to link to the other post. There might have been other reasons for the deletion

Comment: Imagine checking encyclopedia and found a single term being defined twice on page 231 and page 401, and they are basically duplicates except subtle differences in way of description after you read both of them. Answering known duplicate question is giving all future visitor that kind of experience, and I couldn't call it a "good faith" move.

Comment: To commenters: No error message. No other deleted answers. No other accounts past or present. The question is at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58785876/need-help-find-the-missing-code-to-find-the-digit-count-of-the-function/58785987#58785987. Sorry I didn't think of that myself.

Comment: If you do receive any message at all, what makes you think you lost your answering privileges?

Comment: @rbrtn: If you don't get any error message, how do you know then that your answer privilege is gone? Or better to say: If you would be answer banned, then you would for sure get an error message stating that.

Comment: About your answer: I guess the question was deleted because it's a well known duplicate and all of the answers are wrong/incomplete. Yours, for example, does only return the correct digit count for positive integers.

Comment: Hi, I voted to close and delete that question. The accepted answer in the duplicate mentions the exact same thing as your answer. There are plenty of alternatives too. The question lacks any sort of research and adds no additional value to the site.

Comment: @BDL The answer isn't even correct for large positive integers, e.g. `getDigitCount(1e50);` returns 5

Comment: I know I lost my answering privileges because the submit button was grayed out and unresponsive to clicks when I tried to use it and I got zero messages. Good point on the positive integers.  Just shows how much I still don't know. To adiga: I reluctantly agree with your rationale for deleting the question.

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of what you see when you try to post an answer? And a link to the question you want to answer? It could be a bug and not a ban (or both), if you do not get any message at all. Or the question may not be accepting answers at all.

Comment: @rbrtn You probably tried to answer a protected question or something. I'm pretty sure you still have your answer privileges, but specific questions require reputation to answer

Comment: The question I tried to answer was a new one, so I don't think it could have been protected. Considering that my answer was inadequate even as a solution to the questioner's very basic problem, I now believe the deletion of the answer - and the points I got for it - was well justified.  Nevertheless, I think beginners should be warned away from this site, to spare them the experience I and the questioner have had.

Comment: @rbrtn I am not privileged enough to see question but the title of the question in url is `need-help-find-the-missing-code-to-find-the-digit-count-of-the-function` which sounds like a homework question, which is why it was deleted.

Comment: @ErikA OP has more than 10 reputation (and has since Nov 9th) so they can answer protected questions.

Comment: @wha7ever Homework questions are not inherently off-topic (which is what you mean when you say it was deleted). They just have specific requirements that other questions do not.

Comment: Never mind the deleted question. Do you still say you have "lost your answering privileges"?

Comment: @TylerH True. But it starts with "need help", followed by "find the missing code", which prompts me to ask "what have you done so far to find that missing code?". Maybe question lacked research? But whatever.

Comment: I don't know enough about how this site works to say for certain that I no longer have answering privileges. All I know is that, an hour ago or so, I tried to answer a question and couldn't submit the answer. I haven't tried answering any questions since then. I've lost my appetite for answering questions anyway.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I answer if the question isn't accepting answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354071/how-can-i-answer-if-the-question-isnt-accepting-answers)

Comment: Would an answer ban on SO carry over to meta-SO? Because if so, you could test the answer ban idea by trying to post a dummy answer on this question. though I'm not 100% sure if bans carry over that way. Can anyone confirm?

Comment: @DavisBroda I'm pretty sure q-bans are per site. If not, a lot of poor souls, even high-reps, would be quality banned here ...

Comment: I've just made a new discovery. In the time since I made my meta posting the one programming question I had asked on this site (this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58774697/get-an-objects-name-as-the-value-of-this) seems to have disappeared from my record, along with two reputation points. Maybe this is some mistake or another well-justified action, or maybe my paranoid suspicion of petty vindictiveness isn't paranoid. I also seem to have misplaced 3 or 4 badges.

Comment: @rbrtn I think you confused yourself.  Your [meta profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/12345356/rbrtn) and [main user profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12345356/rbrtn) are different.  The latter still has your question.  The 2 points you lost were due to someone down voting your answer, as can be seen on your [reputation tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12345356/rbrtn?tab=reputation).

Comment: Hmm! I haven't been here long enough to get used to this site's organization but I know that the question's votes were above zero for days before I made my meta posting. And my badges are still missing.

Comment: [These are your badges](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12345356/rbrtn?tab=badges). Maybe you should stop with the accusations.

Comment: Thanks. Nice to have them back!

Comment: @rbrtn They almost surely never left.

Comment: Once again I'm confused by the site's design. On the top bar of every page there's a number next to the score number. Hovering over the number identifies it as the number of badges you have. Isn't that number identical on every page where it appears?

Comment: @rbrtn you have the same number of reputation points on a main site and on meta, but meta has its own set of badges.

Comment: Thanks for that info Dan. My ignorance is an ocean.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Nevertheless, I answered in good faith, using code examples written by me. Penalizing learners for their newbie mistakes seems harsh for a site that purports to support all comers in their efforts to learn and help.

Unfortunately for your case, that's not how Stack Overflow works. *People* (e.g. "learners") are involved only as a function to create useful content; the point and goal of the site, at least originally, is to create a useful repository for programming Q&A (without excessive duplication). While that's changing over time as the company behind the site focuses more on profit than on quality, that mission statement has not been directly countered by staff to my knowledge.

In some cases, duplicates are useful because they act as signposts to the best, most canonical question and set of answers on a specific subject for people who might Google things a bit differently than we'd expect. In other cases, though, duplicates are not useful, either because we simply have so many duplicates already or because the specific permutation of the duplicate is such that it's contrived or specific to the point of not being particularly applicable to anyone beside the asker.

It's great that you answered a question and that it was accepted. Keep that drive to help others! But also try to keep in mind that, if you get the feeling a question is very basic, and has probably been answered before, then it's better for you to spend some time looking for a duplicate instead of writing an answer. You *can* do both, and just wait to submit the answer until after you've been unsuccessful in finding a duplicate... but it's better for you in this case and for the OP to focus on finding that duplicate first.

> I few minutes ago I tried to answer another question and found that my answering privileges have also been rescinded.

What you probably mean is that you've been [temporarily answer-banned](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans). It's important to note this doesn't happen from a single deleted answer (certainly not one that was accepted and possibly upvoted!); you need to have multiple negatively-scored and/or deleted answers to land an answer ban. See

> The ban will be lifted automatically by the system when it determines that your positive contributions outweigh those answers which were poorly received.

If you need assistance with this, a moderator can give you links to any deleted answers of yours that you may have lost or forgotten about. As always, you (and anyone else) can see any undeleted answers of your own by visiting your own profile page.

Comment: Thank you, Tyler, for your full and informative answer. To date, I have made one meta posting (this one), asked one question and tried to give one answer, and I recall neither of the latter two getting a single downvote. Nontheless, I realize nothing fashioned by humans is perfect. I have no serious problem with the ban.

Comment: @rbrtn Is not currently and has never previously been banned from posting answers.

Comment: @CodyGray Interesting; I wonder then what scenario he encountered that didn't allow him to answer. If he wasn't banned, and he can answer protected questions, it must have either been a different site altogether or a closed question that he tried to answer (or he tried to answer a question with 20/30+ answers and mistook the "are you sure you want to add another answer?" banner for a "you can't answer" one)...

Comment: Or the site went temporarily offline because some joker ran an expensive query against 2.5 million users in a SQL database. I don’t really know. The moderator tools don’t include a playback of all a user’s actions. :-)

Comment: The question I tried unsuccessfully to answer was a new one about JavaScript. It had few or no previous answers, which is why I took the trouble to try.  Aside from trying to help someone who happens to know less than I do, I was trying to broaden, deepen, and re-enforce my own understanding. Until now, though, I didn't understand that answering a question on this site can be a minefield for a newbie.